# Using middleware in laravel to determine page visits

Tags: laravel, middleware

```php
Public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $count = 0;
    $time = now();
    $visitor = "Someone";

    if (request("visitor") == "Someone" && $count == 0) {
        $count++;
        \Mail::raw('You have a new page visit at ' . $time ' ' . $count . '', function ($note) {
            $note->to('manager@mail.com');
        });

        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return abort (404);
    }
```

This code is just a simple middleware to check a page visit in laravel. It‘a working fine and I’m receiving the email via log. However, the count is just 1 on every page hit. It doesn’t increase to 2, 3......

I really need help to be able to count the page hits regardless of who or what visits, even regardless of IP. Plus how do I fetch the counts to a view and also save it in the database. I really need help as I’m still a learner. Please help!

Comment: Your count will never increase past 1 because you're redeclaring it every time the middleware is called. What you're trying to do would probably be best done by an analytics service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar once to this, but for the system's issues encountered by users. Since you want to measure traffic (using the database), the scenario is kinda similar. Let's say you have a table called traffic, so the logic in regards that traffic would be placed in the handle function at the middleware as you have but measuring traffic like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $time = now(); // @Todo: check timezone in the config/app.php

    $visitor = $request->ip();
    $traffic = Traffic::where('visitor', $visitor)->first();

    if ($traffic) {
        // Resident visitor
        $traffic->visits++;
        $traffic->update();

    } else {
        // New visitor
        $traffic = new Traffic(['visitor' => $visitor]);
        $traffic->save();

        $totalTraffic = Traffic::all()->sum('visits');
        $totalVisitors = Traffic::all()->count();

        // Email notification
        \Mail::raw("There is a new visitor at {$time} from ip {$visitor}.\nIn total there are {$totalVisitors} visitors, and over all you have {$totalTraffic} visits.", function ($note) {
            $note->to('manager@mail.com');
        });
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Keep in mind you can improve this solution by moving the traffic logic into the Traffic model by implementing a boot function inside the model, that would look cleaner. More info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers

Sorry I got late, hope it helps though...

**Solution 2:**
You could also create a migration or run the following statement in your database, setting a default column for visits as 1, since it won't change every time a new one is created.

> ALTER TABLE traffic ALTER visits SET DEFAULT 1;

Traffic Model:

```
class Traffic extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['visitor' , 'visits'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($traffic) {
            if ($traffic->visits) {
                $traffic->visits++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TrafficMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $time = now();

    $visitor = $request->ip();
    $traffic = Traffic::firstOrCreate(['visitor' => $visitor]);
    $traffic->save();

    //Email notification
    $totalTraffic = Traffic::all()->sum('visits');
    $totalVisitors = Traffic::all()->count();

    \Mail::raw("New visit at {$time} from {$visitor}. You have over all {$totalTraffic} visits from {$totalVisitors} visitors.", function ($note) {
        $note->to('manager@mail.com');
    });

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hmg for additional help. So my Traffic model will have table columns like : ID, visits, IP address and time stamps right? And if I move the logic into Traffic model, how does the middleware detect the page visit by the route? I am sorry for the questions, I just want to be sure how it all works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure @cd4success. Your model could start easy like that, and could also grow over-time really depends on your needs, but will allow you some flexibility to start with.
In order to attach the middleware to your routes, you need to make sure the middleware is loaded at the **app/Http/Kernel.php** in your routes middleware array, with something like  `...,'traffic' => \App\Http\Middleware\TrafficMiddleware::class ]`
For the middleware in your routes use the web.php routes file:
`Route::group(['middleware' => 'traffic'], function () {
    // All desired tracking routes in here...
});`

Comment: Thank you very much @hmg. I’ll make use of this also. But please I have one final question. I have three pages (Home, Posts and About). These three pages can be viewed by anyone who visits the site. However, there are some pages containing contents in between header and footer which only signed in users have access to. I’m finding it hard to use auth middleware to hide the content. Not sure of how to use the directives like at-guest, at-auth and so on. Please I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: No problem @cd4success, I've added a second solution, so you can see how would the model logic look like when called from the traffic middleware. Not sure what you've tried so far for the auth middleware, maybe this link can help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/restricting-pieces-of-a-view ...

Answer (score 1):

First, if you redeclare `$count` every time, it will never increase.

Second, you're checking if `$count` is equal to 0 before sending the message, so even if it did increase, you would not send the mail next time.

One way to persist the count value would be using cache.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // retrieve cached value for 'page_visits'. If it doesn't exist, return 0 instead
    $count = cache('page_visits', 1);
    $visitor = request()->ip();
    $time = now();

    \Mail::raw("You have a new page visit at {$time->isoFormat('LLLL')} from {$visitor}. Total: {$count}", function ($note) {
        $note->to('manager@mail.com');
    });

    cache()->put('page_visits', ++$count);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @IGP. Your solution worked, however it didn’t persist the value. It kept logging 1...1...1...not increasing to 2 and 3 and 4....... How do I solve this please? And how I can send the counter to a view?

Comment: I have just tested this out and it works on my end. You can also just retrieve the cache value in the view with the `cache()` helper. For example: `<h1>Page visits: {{ cache('page_visits', 0) }}</h1>`

Comment: I have checked every detail of the code and missed nothing, still it doesn’t increment. But the “cache()put->” that comes after the mail does not show any value at all. I had to move it at the top of the email, then it showed 1, not increment whatsoever. Please check the code because I have checked it thoroughly. Are you getting increment as you refresh or revisit the page you attach the middleware to? Please let me know.

Comment: please find it in your heart to forgive me. I just saw my mistake from the very top. ```cache(‘page_visits,1’);  ..... cache(‘page_visits’, 1); .....```. It worked like a charm! Thanks so so much. The counts increment in the log and also on the page. You just saved a life...

Comment: One last thing @IGP. Please is there a way I can use Carbon to determine the visits by minutes or hours or days or weeks ago?

Comment: A typo happens to everyone, don't worry about it. There's the `diffForHumans()` method but I don't think it's going to work for this particular scenario. Example: `$carbon = now()->addHours(2); echo $carbon->diffForHumans();` will produce the string `2 hours from now`

Comment: Thanks a lot @IGP. The solution is what I really wanted. I’ll apply it to other routes.